# Laravel registration with Auth doesnt work

Tags: php, laravel, registration, user-registration, laravel-authentication

I'm trying to regist a user with the Auth that Laravel provides and I can't. Also, I'm doing the login and registration in the same view (index). With a button I change views to login o register. All of this happend in the sidenav

This are my Routes:

```
//Auth routes
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@home')->name('home');

Route::view('/', 'layouts/index');

Route::view('/profile', 'layouts/profile');
Route::get('/welcome', 'UserController@getUsers');

    // Authentication Routes
Route::post('/', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('/', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::post('/', 'Auth\RegisterController@create')->name('register');
```

This is the registration view:

```
    <button type="button" id="registGoBackButton" class="btn accessButtons goBackButton" style="display:block;"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
  <div class="row user-view">
    <blockquote  style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:30px;"><h3 style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:30px;">Register</h3></blockquote>
    <form class="" action="{{ route('register') }}" method="POST">
      @csrf
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input name="name" id="registName" type="text" class="validate" required value="">
        <label for="name">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input name="username" id="registUsername" type="text" class="validate" required value="{{ old('username') }}">
        <label for="username">{{ __('Username') }}</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input name="email" id="registEmail" type="email" class="validate" required value="">
        <label for="email">{{ __('Email') }}</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input name="password" id="registPassword" type="password" class="validate" required>
        <label for="password">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
      </div>
     <button class="col s4 btn waves-effect #00796b teal darken-2" type="submit" name="action" style="margin-top:30px;">Submit
        <i class="material-icons"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

And this is my Registration Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = 'welcome';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:225|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*[...] and I can't."* Why not? What happens? Are you getting an error? Gonna need more details. At a glance, it looks like you're creating the user, but then never logging them in.

Comment: I'm getting this now "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

Answer (score 5):

The issue is due to the controller action. Your form should be posting to `RegisterController@register` function rather than the `create()` function. So, just change your route to:

```
// Registration Routes...
Route::post('/', 'Auth\RegisterController@register')->name('register');
```

If you look at your `RegisterController`, you'll notice it includes the `RegistersUsers` trait which contains the `register()` method:

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using `array $data` in your `create` method, but if you replace

```
protected function create(array $data)
```

with

```
protected function create(Request $request)
```

Also, make sure to have

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

at the top of your controller, then use

```
return User::create([
  'name' => $request->input('name'),
  'username' => $request->input('username'),
  'email' => $request->input('email'),
  'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
]);
```

instead of `$data['{variable}']`.

Since your `POST` route is hooked up, it's automatically sending a `Request` object to the method that's handling it, but you're declaring it as an array and accessing it improperly.

Also, currently, `protected function validate()` is not being called, as there's not route connected to it. Move that into `create()`:

```
protected function create(Request $request){

  $this->validate($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'username' => 'required|string|max:225|unique:users',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
  ]);
  ...
}
```

Sidenote: This kinda looks like it should be a Resource Controller, connected via `Route::resource()`, but I'm not sure; I don't use them personally.

Full `RegisterController` would look like:

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

```
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller {
    protected function create(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:225|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'username' => $request->input('username'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
        ]);

        return back()->with(["status" => "success", "message" => "User Created!");
        // Accessible on the frontend via `session()->get("message", "");`
    }
}
```

Comment: Thaks for the answer, men. Now i'm having this error 
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException thrown with message "Cannot redeclare App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create()"

Stacktrace:
#0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException in C:\xampp\htdocs\DebateMe\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php:56

Comment: Means you've got two instances of `protected function create()` somewhere :P

Comment: Might have been a bit unclear, but `$this->validate` and `return User::create()` are both in the `create()` function. Let me update the question; show the full function.

Comment: Thank for the dedication, Tim. Don't wanna bother you but now I'm having another error, jjajaja. 
"Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\DebateMe\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php on line 13"
The line 13 is:
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',

Comment: Ah; likely `$request->all()`; remove `->all()` from that; should work. I usually use manual Validators, and the signature is a bit different.

Comment: Now I have no errors!! But hace my inicial problem. Once I press the submit button, the page redirect to themself, but in my DB does not appear the user

Comment: Your validation is likely failing; I think your form is missing a `password_confirmation` field.